# Combinar filas en un df

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo este df en Rstudio en el que se repiten valores en distintas filas y quiero agruparlas por "value" (por ejemplo, la fila 1 con la 9, y que me sume "n" en cada caso). Probé con group_by() y no me sale. El problema (creo) es que la cadena de textos no son exactamente iguales: en las primeras nueve el texto comienza con un espacio. Entonces necesitaría eliminar el espacio al principio de la cadena (esta sería la mejor solución porque esto me ocurre con data frames mucho más grandes) para poder hacerlo con la función group_by, o encontrar otra manera de hacerlo.

```
|   |  value               |         n|
| 1 |" Auto Particular"     |       32|
| 2 |" Bicicleta"      |             7|
| 3 |" Moto"     |                   2|
| 4 |" Premetro"    |                6|
| 5 |" Subte"            |          30|
| 6 |" Taxi/remis/cabify/otros"  |  28|
| 7 |" Tren"              |         61|
| 8 |" Voy solo caminando"        | 10|
| 9 |"Auto Particular"  |          62|
|10 |"Bicicleta"        |            7|
|11 | "Colectivo"           |       221|
|12 |"Moto"         |                3|
|13 |"Subte"             |           3|
|14 |"Taxi/remis/cabify/otros"  |    4|
|15 |"Tren"             |            6|
|16 |"Voy solo caminando"        |  12|
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, ten en cuenta que una pregunta debe estar **bien complementada**, es decir, debes demostrar lo que **has intentado**, de otra manera, se puede tomar como que estás pidiendo ayuda para un examen o tarea y esto no es bien visto en el sitio. Puedes referenciarte del siguiente [enlace](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Si tu problema es simplemente el espacio al comienzo, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(value = str_trim(value, "both")) %>% 
  group_by(value) %>% 
  summarize(n=n())
```

[`str_trim()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_trim.html) junto con `mutate()` acondiciona los valores eliminando los espacios no significativos, los del comienzo y el final de la cadena